# What sort of injuries to structures near the tendon may happen during an autologous blood injection?

Tags: tendinopathy, injury, epicondylitis, tendons, autologous-blood-inject

One of the risks of [autologous blood injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autologous_blood_injection) is injury to structures near the target tendon.

Example:
http://www.sportsmed.net.nz/patient-info/general-rehabilitation/autologous-blood-injections/:

> Pain was one of the main problems reported. In one study of 35 patients, 25 had pain and stiffness after the procedure, which went away within 2 days. Most patients reported that the pain was similar to the pain they had after steroid injection. Other potential complications include infection, **injury to structures near the tendon** and bruising at the injection site.

What sort of injuries to structures near the tendon may happen during an autologous blood injection?

I wonder which structures are at risks, as well as the level of the risk (e.g., recovery duration and activity limitation).

I am mostly interested in lateral epicondylitis of the humerus, but curious about other tendon as well.

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.